# How do front-end developers test pages when the files they are handed are PHP views?

Tags: php, testing, git, front-end, laravel

Someone who has a PHP project invited me to do the front-end work on his site.  I don't know PHP, I've only ever worked with HTML/CSS/JS files.  I cloned the project files from GitHub, and all of the html is generated using controllers and views in the Laravel framework.

So here's the question: as a front-end developer, am I expected to have a MAMP or some other kind of local development server to be able to test PHP files?  I want to be able merge my commits to the master branch of his project, but he understandably doesn't want me to do that without testing.  Or is normal to just send him the my branch commits and let him test and merge them into the master himself?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this. You need to discuss with your colleague, not the Internet. I will say that in general one should test code before committing it, but the specific details of how that testing is accomplished is determined by a combination of the technologies used, available servers, and what the team decides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Snowman, but as to not leave you empty handed, I will discuss a few possibilities.
If by 'doing the front-end work', you have primarily been tasked with *designing* the project, then you can *design* the site according to your normal workflow and simply pass it off to him to integrate it.
If you are responsible for everything client-side, then you will have establish a workflow with your partner, which could be as simple as maintaining a separate fork of the project that both of you have access to. He can then merge it in when he feels that it's ready.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's precisely what we worked out.  Just wondering if it was a common workflow issue, this is my first project with another person.